# calling an button in another layout to perform action in some other java class

Tags: android, android-widget

I am a newbie to Android

I am having two screens attached with this question.

First Screen layout:

[image: Screen one Layout]

Second Screen Layout:

[image: Screen two Layout]

I have one java class - MyAccount to collect these data and process but when I get Scree2.jpg layout I cannot have the action of the button "Save Email Id's" of the screen2 written in the same class MyAccount.
Second Screen layout
I am not able to take "Save the Email Id's" Button action and listener in the same MyAccount class.

```
 Button btnCallSalesEmail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCallSalesEmailWindow);
btnCallSalesEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.myaccount_email_layout);


        EmailLoad();

        System.out.println("After MyAccountSalesEmailLoad");
    }

});
```

What should I do to write a action and listener for "Save Email Id's" 
    button in Screen2(which is in different layout )  in the same 
    `MyAccount` class.

This layout does not have another Java class, but I want to write 
    action and listener for a button in previous class which had called this layout.

Looking for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't!
Your classes are Activities, so only one is active at the same time and they cannot communicate directly between each other.

But you can certainly pass data from one activity to another.
There is actually an entry on the Android FAQ on this subject : http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3 
I agree this is not crystal clear which one to use when.
For your needs you must use the first entry, the `Intent.putExtras()` way.

Intents can contain the data you wan to transfer (backward or forward).
Therefore you have two solutions here depending of your business logic.

### You need to send the data from your first activity Screen1 to the second one Screen2.

You will be doing that by adding extras to the intent used to launch it.

*Screen1.class*

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { //click event for the sales email button
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen2.class);
    i.putExtra("name", value1);
    i.putExtra("lastname", value2);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And read them in the second Activity.

*Screen2.class*

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String valName = i.getStringExtra("name");
String valLastname = i.getStringExtra("lastname");
```

### Or you need to get data back from your activity Screen2 to Screen1

Start your activity explicitly requesting a result.

*Screen1.java*

```
private static final int GET_EMAIL_REQUEST = 42;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { //click event for the sales email button
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen2.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, GET_EMAIL_REQUEST);
}
```

Provide the result and end the second Activity.

*Screen2.java*

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { //click event for the save the email's id button
    Intent i = getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("mail", "stackoverflow@rocks.com");
    this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Read the result back in the first Activity.

*Screen1.java*

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
             Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GET_EMAIL_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // mail has been filled.
            String mail = intent.getStringExtra("mail");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks but there is still some confusion...there is function this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); in Screen2.java, is setResult an inbuilt function, throwing up an exception at that line and Intent i = getIntent(); and in next line rather than to use i, you have used intent. Looking for your reply.

Comment: I get the ecxeption The method setResult() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener() for the line...........this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

Comment: setResult() is a method of the Activity object, not the ClickListener object, hence the error. In order to call setResult() you need a reference to your current Screen2 activity object. Inside an anonymous inner class (means: enclosed, on the fly declared) you can acces the outer class like this: Screen2.this.setResult()